# How can I use addObject in Array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray

I have a NSMutableArray *arrayFavorite

In the log I see

```
{      name1 = 6;
       name2 = "Paolo Rossi\nIt\U00e1lia";
       name3 = "cartaz-1982.jpg";
       photo = "copa8.jpg";
       name4 = 24;
   },
    {
       name1 = 6;
       name2 = "Oleg Salenko\nR\U00fassia";
       name3 = "cartaz-1994.jpg";
       photo = "copa5.jpg";
       name4 = 24;
   },
```

I need transforme this

```
self.tableItems = @[[UIImage imageNamed:@"photo1.jpg"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"photo2.jpg"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"photo3.jpg"]];
```

For get dynamic info photo name from my *array Favorite

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking how to get the value `photo` from you array `arrayFavorite` and then use that to populate the name parameter for `+ (UIImage *)imageNamed:(NSString *)name`?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is enumerate through the array of dictionaries and create an image using the `photo` keyValue through `+imageNamed:...`.

```
NSArray *imageInfoDicts = ...;
NSMutableArray *images = [NSMutableArray array];
[imageInfoDicts enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary *dictionary, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    [images addObject[UIImage imageNamed:dictionary[@"photo"]]];
}];
NSLog(@"%@", images);
```

Answer (score 0):

As it looks like you are showing this data in a tableView you should probably grab the data for the particular row and then get the image at that point in time to avoid loading all your images into memory at one time.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:<identifier> forIndexPath:indexPath];

  NSDictionary *item = self.items[indexPath.row];

  cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:item[@"photo"]];

  return cell;
}
```